# Trying to run my application but suffering wth "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, reduce, vite

I'm trying to run a transactions application but Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce') error doesn't let me run the app. My screen turns into a full white btw. It was running just ok, and then suddenly boom, not working anymore:
[image]

This is my Summary index.tsx:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import incomeImg from '../../assets/income.svg'
import outcomeImg from '../../assets/outcome.svg'
import totalImg from '../../assets/total.svg'
import { useTransactions } from '../../hooks/useTransactions'

import { Container } from './styles'

export function Summary() {

  const {transactions} = useTransactions()

  const summary = transactions.reduce((acc,transaction)=>{

    if (transaction.type === 'deposit'){
      acc.deposit += transaction.amount
      acc.total += transaction.amount
    } else {
        acc.withdraw = transaction.amount
        acc.total -= transaction.amount
      }

    return acc
    }, {
    deposit: 0,
    withdraw: 0,
    total: 0
  })

return (/*SOME HTML*/)
```

Also putting here my useTransaction hook:
https://gist.github.com/gabrielforster/314e5a5f91d8f83c78a3cc8a56a55435

Comment: Please post the code for your `useTransactions` hook. It will also help to make sure `transactions` is defined before calling `.reduce`

Comment: Generally this happens when whatever you call the function on is undefined. Try printing transactions before using reduce and check for *undefined*

Comment: @ThavasAntonio how to a fix that

Comment: Well if you are getting undefined, please post your useTransactions code.

Answer (score 0):

Best to post the code for `useTransactions()`. Here I'm guessing that it is actually waiting for some data to complete. The best way to handle this is with a `useEffect` which fires when `transactions` is updated and put `summary` in a state. I added a optional chaining check `.?` to check for null or undefined before actually using reduce.

```
    const [summary, setSummary] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setSummary(transactions?.reduce(
            (acc, transaction) => {
                if (transaction.type === 'deposit') {
                    acc.deposit += transaction.amount;
                    acc.total += transaction.amount;
                } else {
                    acc.withdraw = transaction.amount;
                    acc.total -= transaction.amount;
                }

                return acc;
            },
            {
                deposit: 0,
                withdraw: 0,
                total: 0,
            },
        ));
    }, [transactions]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an error on my useTransaction hook guys! Thank you all floks

Comment: Please describe the exact error here. Otherwise, this is not an answer that would help anyone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).